# How do I get latex to output references like this: (e.g. Fujii, 2016, p. 412; Murata, 2010, p. 576)

Tags: biblatex, citing

Latex can output parenthesised references starting with e.g. like

`\parencite[e.g.][]{fujii2016}`, which will result in

> (e.g. fujii, 2016)

But how do I get it to output a reference like this:

> (e.g. Fujii, 2016, p. 412; Murata, 2010, p. 576)?

Comment: Hi, welcome to the site. I assume, due to `\parencite`, that you're using the `biblatex` package, and I change the tags accordingly. Was I correct in that assumption?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

You can use `\parencites` for this:

[image]

The usage, or "pattern", for this macro is like this:

```
\parencites(<multiprenote>)(<multipostnote>)[<prenote>][<postnote>]{<key>}[<prenote>][<postnote>]{<key>}...[<prenote>][<postnote>]{<key>}
```

The first two arguments, delimited by `()` are optional, and are intended for pre/post notes of *the entire list* of citations. Then you add as many instances of

```
[<prenote>][<postnote>]{key}
```

as you want. Both the pre and post notes are for the individual references, and are optional. If you specify just one, that becomes a postnote.

Hence, to obtain something like what you asked for with two citations use

```
\parencites(e.g.)()[1--2]{aksin}[3--4]{angenendt}
```

where `aksin` and `angenendt` are citation keys, and `1--2`/`3--4` their respective page ranges. So yes, perhaps a bit inconvenient, but if the list of references becomes long, then it is probably easier to keep track of pre/post notes this way, than if you could do something like `\parencites[pre_1,pre_2,...,pre_n][post_1,post_2,...,post_n]{key_1,key_2,...,key_n}`.

Complete example:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage[style=authoryear]{biblatex}
\addbibresource{biblatex-examples.bib}
\begin{document}
\parencites(e.g.)()[1--2]{aksin}[3--4]{angenendt}
\printbibliography
\end{document}
```

Comment: `\parencites(e.g.)()[1--2]{aksin}[3--4]{angenendt}` might be more appropriate, judging by the documentation, but the output is the same.

Comment: Tak/Thanks. I have jsut tried but I can't make it work correctly. How can I enter the second (or third, or..) reference? I expected to see the list of references, but it doesn't show up.

Comment: @jbahn My example has two references, continue the same pattern to add more. I'll add some explanations in a bit, you can read the manual section 3.8.3 if you're impatient.

Comment: Ok, I got it:  I have to type the following references manually (this is not very convenient though). Thanks a lot.

Comment: you refer to 'the manual'. I find there is a number of them. Which one are you referring to?

Comment: @jbahn `\parencites` is defined by `biblatex`, so the manual of `biblatex`. Run `texdoc biblatex` in a terminal to open the docs installed with your TeX distribution, or visit e.g. http://texdoc.net/.

Comment: Tak for hjælpen / Thanks a lot (am I allowed to use non-English?)

Comment: @jbahn The odd comment in other languages, like that one, doesn't hurt, but in general use English.