# Citing a book chapter in a multiple entry citation?

Tags: natbib, multiple-citations

I would like to be able to cite a specific chapter in a book within a multi-entry citation and have the additional citation information map correctly (full MWE follows this explanation). I found [this solution](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/2515/how-to-cite-chapter-in-book?newreg=bb82967480864a38bbf53a06f786b0a3) for citing a book chapter within a single entry citation, like so:

```
Things and stuff from \citet[Chapter~3]{Okabe2000}.
Stuff and things \citep[Chapter~3]{Okabe2000}.
Some other things \cite[see][Chapter~3]{Okabe2000}.
```

> Things and stuff from Okabe et al. (2000, Chapter 3).
>   Stuff and things (Okabe et al., 2000, Chapter 3).
>   Some other things (see Okabe et al., 2000, Chapter 3).

However, when adding another citation the additional chapter (or page) information is simply appended to the end of the entry, like so:

```
Stuff and things \citep[see][Chapter~3]{Okabe2000, Okabe2013}.
```

> Stuff and things (see Okabe et al., 2000; Okabe and Morioka, 2013, Chapter 3).

where I need "Chapter 3" to be with "Okabe et al., 2000", not "Okabe and Morioka, 2013", like so:

> Stuff and things (see Okabe et al., 2000, Chapter 3; Okabe and Morioka, 2013).

I feel like I am missing some basic functionality in trying to do this (and I may have overlooked something very simple), but I can't seem to figure out how to do it.

---

**MWE**

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage[round,authoryear]{natbib}
\usepackage{filecontents}

\begin{filecontents}{\jobname.bib}
@book{Okabe2000,
address = {Hoboken, NJ, USA},
author = {Okabe, Atsuyuki and Boots, Barry and Sugihara, Kokichi and Chiu, Sung Nok and Kendall, D. G.},
doi = {10.1002/9780470317013},
edition = {2nd},
isbn = {9780470317013},
publisher = {John Wiley {\&} Sons, Inc.},
series = {Wiley Series in Probability and Statistics},
title = {{Spatial Tessellations}},
year = {2000}
}
@misc{Okabe2013,
address = {Dresden, Germany},
author = {Okabe, Atsuyuki and Morioka, Wataru},
pages = {1--16},
title = {{A GIS-based method for converting area-based data to network-based data and its application: Estimating the number of refugees who would walk to the nearest shelter following a large earthquake}},
url = {https://sites.google.com/site/icaworkshop2013/},
year = {2013}
}
\end{filecontents}

\begin{document}

Things and stuff from \citet[Chapter~3]{Okabe2000}.

Stuff and things \citep[Chapter~3]{Okabe2000}.

Some other things \cite[see][Chapter~3]{Okabe2000}.

Both things \citep[see][Chapter~3]{Okabe2000, Okabe2013}.

\bibliographystyle{plainnat}
\bibliography{\jobname}
\end{document}
```

---

**EDIT**

For anyone in the future looking for this in the docs search for 'multicite', not 'multiple citations',
[as pointed out here](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/18910/multiple-citations-with-pages-using-biblatex/18911#18911).

Answer (score 6, accepted):

If this is about `natbib` you can't have multi-cites with postnotes for each citation, you have to work around that limitation with `\citetext` and  `\citealp`.

```
\citetext{\citealp[see][Chap.~3]{sigfridsson}; \citealp{worman}}
```

I.e.

```
\documentclass[british]{article}
\usepackage[T1]{fontenc}
\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}
\usepackage{babel}
\usepackage[round,authoryear]{natbib}

\usepackage{filecontents}
\begin{filecontents}{\jobname.bib}
@article{sigfridsson,
  author  = {Sigfridsson, Emma and Ryde, Ulf},
  title   = {Comparison of methods for deriving atomic charges from the
             electrostatic potential and moments},
  journal = {Journal of Computational Chemistry},
  year    = 1998,
  volume  = 19,
  number  = 4,
  pages   = {377-395},
  doi     = {10.1002/(SICI)1096-987X(199803)19:4<377::AID-JCC1>3.0.CO;2-P},
}
@book{worman,
  author    = {Worman, Nancy},
  title     = {The Cast of Character},
  year      = 2002,
  publisher = {University of Texas Press},
  address   = {Austin},
}
\end{filecontents}

\begin{document}
\citep[see][Chap.~3]{sigfridsson,worman}

\citetext{\citealp[see][Chap.~3]{sigfridsson}; \citealp{worman}}

\bibliographystyle{plainnat}
\bibliography{\jobname}
\end{document}
```

[image: (see Sigfridsson and Ryde, 1998; Worman, 2002, Chap. 3)//(see Sigfridsson and Ryde, 1998, Chap. 3; Worman, 2002)]

See also [citation call-outs separated with a semicolon](https://tex.stackexchange.com/q/324882/35864), [Mimic \parencites using bibtex](https://tex.stackexchange.com/q/197480/35864), [Natbib: Multiple citations with page numbers in one bracket](https://tex.stackexchange.com/q/166097/35864)

---

If you are using `biblatex` you would use the multi-cite commands

```
\parencites[see][Chap.~3]{sigfridsson}{worman}
```

(with an **`s`**).

```
\documentclass[british]{article}
\usepackage[T1]{fontenc}
\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}
\usepackage{babel}
\usepackage{csquotes}
\usepackage[backend=biber, style=authoryear]{biblatex}

\addbibresource{biblatex-examples.bib}


\begin{document}
\parencite[see][Chap.~3]{sigfridsson,worman}

\parencites[see][Chap.~3]{sigfridsson}{worman}
\end{document}
```

[image: (see Sigfridsson and Ryde 1998; Worman 2002, Chap. 3)//(see Sigfridsson and Ryde 1998, Chap. 3; Worman 2002)]

See also [Multiple citations with pages using BibLaTeX](https://tex.stackexchange.com/q/18910/35864), [How do I get latex to output references like this: (e.g. Fujii, 2016, p. 412; Murata, 2010, p. 576)](https://tex.stackexchange.com/q/366567/35864), [\citep for multiple references separated by text](https://tex.stackexchange.com/q/174117/35864),

Comment: Thanks! The `natlib` solution worked and you pointed me to others. I was using the wrong search terms to looks for the answer.... BTW, I upvoted your answer, but it doesn't show because I don't have a high enough reputation.

Comment: @jGaboardi Gad I could help. For future questions you may want to keep in mind that it is easier to answer if one has a bit more background information. Background info should ideally be provided with a short example document (often called MWE: https://tex.meta.stackexchange.com/q/228/35864) that reproduces the output you are getting at the moment. In this case an MWE would have clarified whether you use `natbib` or `biblatex`.