# How to create prefix attached to the second in-text citation in the key?

Tags: citing, natbib

I am new to LaTeX, so maybe it is the stupid question, but I am still unable to figure it out.

I use the `natbib` package:

```
\usepackage{natbib}
\setcitestyle{authoryear,open={(},close={)}}
```

In the main text I'd like to cite two citations as parts of a single key with prefix attached to the second one. Example:

> (see Smith 1999; cf. Doe 1998).

So I used

```
\citep[see]{smith1999, doe1998}
```

to add the first citation signal. But how to add the `cf.` citation signal before the second one?

Comment: You can't do that directly with `\citep`. You'll need something like `\citetext{\citealp[see][Chap.~3]{smith1999}; \citealp[cf.][]{doe1998}}`. See also https://tex.stackexchange.com/q/488092/35864.

Comment: If you are new to LaTeX, then you shouldn't start with `natbib`. Have a look at `biblatex` it is the "state of the art" ...